# Xamarin creating elements dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm working on a project where I have to create an search menu o find specific files, but i need do to create a dinamic search menu because every section has diferents fields of search, and my question is: **How can I create EditTexts,Spinners,etc through code on the activity?**

Comment: enter this in google: "xamarin android create elements programmatically"

Answer (score 0):

```
    //create "reference to your layout"
    LinearLayout yourFormLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout(Resource.Id.Linear_MS);

    //create container for parameters
    var parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

    //add some parameters
    param.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 10);

    //create new element
    Button button = new Button(this);
        button.Text = "click me";
        button.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        button.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        button.LayoutParameters = parameters;

    //add some events to your element
    button.Click += (sender, e) => DoStuff();

        //Add the button
        yourFormLayout.AddView(button);
```

AddView adds element as a child to nearest parent, so if you want some more sofisticated location you'll have to read about for example 'GetDeclaredField'